# Как сделать чтобы в поиске в Opencart выводилось количество товаров?

Tags: opencart

По умолчанию выводить: название, описание и цена, нужно чтобы еще и количество фактическое выводилось.
Подскажите как написать код вывода количества, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если речь про остатки на складах то примерно так https://di-grand.com/blog/opencart/2516-vyvod-kolichestva-tovara-na-sklade-v-kategorii-opencart.html . Если opencart 3x то вместо tpl шаблона надо внести изменения в twig шаблон и соответственно переписать php в twig

Comment: Ну и это про страницу рубрики. Чтобы выводилось именно в поиске - надо править шаблон и контроллер страницы поиска. А еще лучше дописывать эти 2 строчки через свой модификатор ocmod, не внося никаких изменений в сами файлы.